# Removing a new app version from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I created a new version of my app in iTunes Connect using the wrong version number.  I'd like to remove the new version which is in a "Prepare for Upload" status.  How do I do this?

There are other question on SO about this, but they do not provide any answers, apply to a version that has a binary already uploaded, or are out of date.

I have a question in to Apple on this, but have not received a response yet.

Comment: Have you tried gone in there and modifying it?

Comment: Yes. And here are some more characters.

Comment: i encounter the same problem. the apple guys said they don't hv the right to alter or edit our states. but "i hv the ability to edit it" and give me the link to apple developer's guide. actually I CAN'T CHANGE IT!!! post the solution if you get it done

Answer (score 77):

You cannot remove the new version but you can change its version number, as long as you're in the Prepare for Submission state (ie. you might need to remove the build from waiting for review, also known as rejecting the binary, first). Here's how.

To edit the version number, select the falsely numbered version on the left on iTunes Connect (so NOT the "App Information", but under that the version "1.0.1 Prepare for Submission" etc), scroll down in the right pane to "General App Information" -- just below the App Icon you can see the version number and it's editable! Change it, hit save, and you'll see the version number change on the left side.

Update: as @MDH points out, Apple finally got around to making it easier. You can now just directly edit the version number on the main "page" of the unreleased version. Amazing.

Comment: Works in May 2018 as well – thanks! @erik, please accept xaphod's answer!

Comment: You made my day Thanks. Bro. 100000000000 up votes. @xaphod

Comment: Thnx for the answer. Apple should place a button for this. I didn't notice this box was editable.

Comment: Can't remove something you added with a + button? Once again, everything Apple delivers to its devs is substandard and mostly broken until some other part breaks in the next fix. Year after year, month after month, there's always an issue.

Comment: Works in December 2020 :)

Comment: As of December 2022, the General App Information section does not exist in the right pane. Just look for the "Version" field followed by a question mark, it is editable

Answer (score 14):

You cannot remove the new version but you can modify version number,so follow the step.

```
 1. Go to
```

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

and Open the app which you want to modify the version number

```
 2. Go to below step and change the number which you want and display quick response on left panel.
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Log on to itunes connect, then click on the My Apps.
Here we have thumbnails of apps. Click on the app which u have uploaded wrongly. then u will c like this "You can edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review."

click on the link to delete the binary.[image]

Comment: Does not remove the version or change the version number, as the original question asked.

Comment: This answer dose't attempt question . question  is how to remove version and your answer is how to remove  build file.