# How to delete my itunesconnect app with status "Prepare for Submission"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to change my Bundle-ID & SKU but i came to know that its not possible.

So i decided to delete this app and create the new one with appropriate naming, still i didn't submit anything to itunes.

But there is no option for deleting the submission

This is my 1st experience with itunes connect. When i created my 1st project, i gave random Bundle-ID & SKU, now my app is ready and i realised that it should be something else.

Any help will be great.

Comment: Please see the approved answer from Leszek Szary, Now this is possible from 2019. Its easy to delete from 'App Information -> Remove App'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are in **2019** and Apple finally (!) added a possibility to delete an app in "Prepare for Submission" state which was not previously accepted in the App Store at all (for example if you added a test app only for Testflight).

Now you can simply go to "App information" section and at the bottom you will see "Remove App" option which removes the entire application.

[image: Remove App in Prepare for submission state]

Also Apple's website with help: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35 was updated and now it confirms that you can remove apps in "Prepare for Submission" state:

> To remove an app from your main view in My Apps, it must be first
>   removed from the App Store and any associated in-app purchases must be
>   removed from sale.
>
> Additionally, you can only remove apps if all versions of that app are
>   in one of the following states:
>
> - Prepare for Submission
> - Invalid Binary
> - Developer Rejected
> - Rejected
> - Metadata Rejected
> - Developer Removed from Sale
> - Removed from Sale
>
> Apps can’t be removed if they are part of a Game Center group, in an
>   app bundle, currently available on the App Store, associated with
>   in-app purchases available for sale, or if they're being actively
>   transferred to another account.
>
> If the app is part of a Game Center group or app bundle and hasn't
>   been approved yet, it must be removed from the group or bundle before
>   it can be removed from your main view in My Apps. App bundles and
>   approved apps that are part of a Game Center group cannot be removed.

Comment: @jlngdt: Yes, it will delete the entire app and that is exactly what author of this question asked. Please read the question and it's title: "How to delete my itunesconnect app with status “Prepare for Submission”?"

Comment: I don't know why you downvoted as this is the most actuall correct answer to the author's question in current year 2019.

Comment: WARNING: do not use this, it deletes not only app update in state "Prepare for Submission” but whole app!

Comment: @mikep: Yes it deletes the whole app. Author of the question was asking exactly that ("how to delete the app" and not an "app update") so my answer is correct. If you need help with deleting an app update (or in other words specific version) you might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439338/removing-a-new-app-version-from-itunes-connect

Comment: @AlejandroDG You should READ THE QUESTION! Author of this question wrote "i decided to delete this app and create the new one" and he asked "how to delete my itunesconnect app?". He DID NOT ask how to delete an app update but HOW TO DELETE THE WHOLE APP! Question about deleting only an app update is linked in my comment above!

Answer (score 88):

You can change it here (follow the red square as shown below)

In my case i accidentally entered version number '6.0.1' when i actually wanted '6.1'.
The 'version' field is editable. when you change it and hit the 'save' button (give it a second..) it will change.

[image]

Comment: Did that change to 6.1 ? If so, later you might have updated new build pointing to 6.1 .. right ?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Pressing Save immediately updated the version number at the "Prepare for Submission" label.

Answer (score 62):

There is no way to delete an app in that state, according to the  [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html).

> Apps that have not been approved yet can’t be deleted

The only thing we can do for now is to change the name and bundle ID until Apple changes its mind.

**Edit:** Seems that Apple finally made this possible according to Leszek Szary's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238029/how-to-delete-my-itunesconnect-app-with-status-prepare-for-submission/54549768#54549768)

Comment: So if a developer like me created an App by mistake, it cannot be deleted unless approved by Apple?

Comment: Correct. You can change the name and bundle id though, if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Seems a bit strange you can't delete though. There must be so many apps created by mistake.

Comment: Any solution? Can I send to review and delete right way?

Comment: Is there a way to change the bundle id? Since i have uploaded an application with the same bundle id previously it says once build is uploaded it cannot be changed.Is there any solution?

Comment: This is so stupid from Apple... I got the version ID wrong for an update and now there is no way to change it.

Comment: @jsgoupil If you haven't yet submitted your app then you can change your app version by going to prepare for submission.

Comment: It's very unintuitive, but you can simply edit the version number to whatever you need it to be. It seems like you should remove and add a new version, but you actually just edit the current version, instead.

Comment: @dtrenz I found this solution as well, changed the build with one with the new version, but after 'submit for review', no IDFA, the submit button becomes active and then returns to 'submit' once again. No error message, just does not submit.

Comment: Please check my answer on this question.

Comment: Ok guys, we are most likely all software engineers of some type. We deal with difficult problems every day. Let's think of a different solution. Someone should make a generic simple app that will get approved by Apple, and host it on GitHub for all of us to download. When we run into this problem, we send it to Apple on the app we want deleted, and when the approve it, we delete the whole app.

Comment: We are in 2019 and now it is possible to delete the app in prepare for submission state. See my answer below.

Comment: @redHair has a valid answer below.

Comment: Your "EDIT" addition is dangerous because @Leszek Szary`s answer causes deleting not only app update in state "Prepare for Submission” but whole app!

Comment: @mikep yes it deletes the whole app as that was asked in this question. See my explanation under my answer if you need help with deleting only a specific version.

Answer (score 17):

As of Year 2017, everything is still the same.. what a shame

This rule is so counter-intuitive especially for people who plan to test the app with testflight like us..

I don't know if this is gonna work. But we will prepare two apple accounts, one for testing and just name the SKU and etc whatever works. The other one is the official account use to submit app to app store..

Hope it will get fixed soon.

Comment: this is so stupid of apple. I messed up on the version numbers and now cant change it. what was apple thinking

Comment: You can change version number - scroll down version screen, there will be version field under the app icon (after Build section). Change it to version number that you can submit binary with, then put it into review and the reject it by yourself.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @KrishnaKarki they asked "How can **I** delete ..." emphasis on the **I**

Comment: You can contact apple same way I did. Thanks

Comment: As of Year 2018, everything is still the same.. what a shame. Regular apple users wouldnt know the struggle and the pain for us engineer to deal with App Store, so much "the-so-called-the-most-user-friendliest-system-on-the-planet" **sigh

Comment: In 2019 you can finally delete it as I described in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I saw many people experiencing this issue. The only way update version is to contact apple team. Here is it how I did.

Click on the help icon on the iTunesconnect and click on contact us. Check screenshot. [image]

You will see

1. Please choose from the following topics: (select itunes connect upload or general error help)

Now you will see 
 **If you need further assistance resolving your iTunes Connect error message, contact us.**
Now click on contact us and you will see contact form like this. 
[image]

Write your issue properly with your apple id. You will get the option to change version once they review your issue.

It took me only one day to get their reply. You will get email like this from apple team. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also got the version ID wrong for an update and then there was no way to change it.

I think the best way is to update the build numbering. go to project and under identity section increment the build number.

for me it was

`Version : 1.4.3`
`Build :0.4`

I changed it to

`Version : 1.4.3`
`Build :0.5`

I didn't find any other solution to my problem. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is fixing the issue at hand, but I managed to change my wrongly assigned version number by simply going to the "General App Information" section in the bad version and updating it in the textfield!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works with new apps that don't have published versions yet but if it does you'll first need to set the old version to "Remove from Sale". After that you'll be able to remove the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

First, submit your app for review purpose, after some time (In my case 3hr) remove option will appear on your app version details page, you can remove build and upload new build again with the same version but after removal of the build, it takes some time before uploading again.