# How to Delete App from itunes connect, which is in Prepare For Submission Phase

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've uploaded a new app in Itunes Connect and saved some details like App Name,Icon.

I did not submit it for review, just only saved the details.
Now i could not see any option to delete the current App.

Please suggest me !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete my itunesconnect app with status "Prepare for Submission"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238029/how-to-delete-my-itunesconnect-app-with-status-prepare-for-submission)

Comment: Currently it is possible to delete the app in this case. See my answer in similar question linked in previous comment as a duplicate by JZAU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple says

> Apps that have not been approved yet can’t be deleted; instead, reject
>   the app. Apps must have at least one approved version before they can
>   be deleted.

One solution is to rename that application and then use the name by creating a new one. Apple accepts the name and the app will then be in review. Ref: [How to delete an app which is waiting for upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114051/how-to-delete-an-app-which-is-waiting-for-upload)

Comment: My App is in Prepare for Submission. I did not uploaded any binary. just app name and app icon and about app. Now how to delete the app. I could not see any Delete option in current App Section

Comment: Alas, you cannot delete it straightaway. You can rename it and upload a different app. It will sit there for a very long time. It's just how Apple does things, I'm sorry to say. This is a common and frustrating problem. The alternative is to submit a binary, have it _approved_, then you can delete it.

Comment: Oh... How long it would be idle in My App Section.... I don't have any new app to upload for recent being.

Comment: 6 months or more! Apple will sent you a notice that will delete it due to inactivity.

Comment: oh k. is there any fast process to delete the app by writing to apple. any support or contact team. Please let me know about it

Comment: We've tried. I've tried. They refer us to their docs which is the link I shared. That's why I knew this answer so quickly. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75577/discussion-between-imran-and-pjeet-singh).

Comment: This is very annoying, not be able to delete your own application whenever you want to even if it has only the "Prepare for Submission" status. Really lame.